# How to mask out everything but main leaf using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I've got an image of a leaf:

[image]

and I need to make everything except for the leaf in the middle black. How can I do this using opencv in python? A couple things:

- The images have really inconsistent backgrounds, so we cannot rely on masking by color or anything like that.
- Finding contours may, end up with contours merged with the background (unless done really right)
- I think a possibility would be to do something with edges found by `cv2.Canny` (just a thought)

Any help?

Comment: I suspect you will need to use deep learning / ai solution since you have similar color in the background and the leaf has uneven illumination and the tip is a different color.

Comment: find a model for semantic segmentation, try it with opencv. I believe opencv recently gained at least an example for using SAM. browse https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog

Comment: You should try Segment Anything: [demo](https://segment-anything.com/), [code](https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything)

Comment: Its not working. When I run generate(), it takes more than a minute and then my kernel crashes. Does this need cuda to run? I am limited to using my cpu.